# how do you enter a nonlcon in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How do you enter a nonlcon into MATLAB's fmincon function.  I can't seem to find a good example of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this documentation page: [Constrained Nonlinear Optimization Examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/brn4nh7.html)

(The idea is that you need to create another file for the non-linear constraints, and give that function handle as argument)

Comment: I understand that I can create a new file.  The point of my question was to see if I can do it through an anonymous function

Comment: you can't write an anonymous function that returns multiple output arguments, hence you create it as a separate function..